# how is a REST API is routed to back end controller where FOSRestBundle is used to create services?

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

Here is a scenario - http://ic.local/api/adds/disclosuers is the URL to create a disclouser and on click of form submit below data gets `POST` to the URL.

```
{"gm_restbundle_tdtlsdisc":{"isClassified":"N","isExportControl":"N","discTitle":"test","firstRecordedDate":"06-December-2016","estimatedTime":"5","shareOutsideGM":"N"}}
```

But when I look into backend PHP Symfony code I am not able to locate which controller is handling this POST request. There is not such `adds` class having `disclosuers` method.

If `FOSRestBundle` is used, will it carry any different mechanism? I searched for `adds/disclosuers` all over the project. but I see it only in one Angular JS file where the POST URL is mentioned.

I am clueless.

Comment: do you have access to symfony console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [debug](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/debug.html) to debug your router.

`app/console debug:router` will show you the list of registered routes

`app/console debug:router ROUTE_NAME` will show you details of specific route including controller attached to this route

Comment: Thanks . it helped me to know route name post_add_disclosuer but if I want to add a new service how do I add a new route?.

Comment: I use route annotations and method annotations to control the api routing.